# What does the speaker say here between "Über viele Jahre" and "Erforderung"?

Tags: listening-comprehension

I've got a german audio book. In one of its chapters the speaker says:

"Über viele Jahre <s>in bekarrte</s> ich beruflich mit der Erforderung von Führungsqualität in Unternehmen zu tun"

[Here](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/d/d82v3E7V8kqh7w) is the audio file.

What does he say in the striken section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Über viele Jahre hinweg hatte ich beruflich mit der Förderung von Führungsqualität in Unternehmen zu tun.

Über einen Zeitraum hinweg = over a timespan. The 'hinweg' somewhat implies continuously and/or often or repeatedly.

Note also that it says 'Förderung' (and not Erforderung - that wouldn't even be a word).

Basically the sentence means that the speaker was for many years in the business of improving (or supporting) leadership quality within businesses

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it turns out, the word `hinweg` was diminishing the listening comprehension there. And the verb `hatte` or `haben` now makes `zu tun` at the end, meaningful. It roughly translates into "I have with the improvement of leadership quality many years of (experience) to do" (to do => zu tun) As for my transcription of Erforderung, I was thinking of the nominative of the verb `erfordern` but there is no such a word, as you pointed out.